# How do I update tor in Devuan

Tags: debian, command-line, software-updates, tor, devuan

Well, I was trying to enter some onion sites but I wasn't able to, so I checked my tor version and it was `Tor version 0.2.9.16 (git-9ef571339967c1e5).`, do you guys know how to update on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can update torbrowser from command line through `torbrowser-launcher` command after installing the [`torbrowser-launcher`](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/stage/ceres/ceres/torbrowser-launcher_0.3.2-5.html) package, it is only available for devuan ceres (unstable). `contrib` component should be added to your sources URLs.

Package description [from debian](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/torbrowser-launcher):

> helps download, update and run the Tor Browser Bundle
>
> Tor Browser Launcher is intended to make the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) easier to maintain and use for GNU/Linux users. torbrowser-launcher handles downloading the most recent version of TBB for you, in your language and for your architecture. It also adds a "Tor Browser" application launcher to your operating system's menu.
>
> When you first launch Tor Browser Launcher, it will download TBB from https://www.torproject.org/ and extract it to ~/.local/share/torbrowser, and then execute it. Cache and configuration files will be stored in ~/.cache/torbrowser and ~/.config/torbrowser. Each subsequent execution after installation will simply launch the most recent TBB. Tor Browser will be fetched, verified and unpacked each time a new version of TBB is released. **When you open Tor Browser Launcher after an update**, it will download the newer version of TBB for you and extract it over your old TBB directory in ~/.local/share/torbrowser, so you will maintain your TBB bookmarks.